# (Real Analysis) Topology: Prove $f(cl S)\subseteq clf(S)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show: $f(\overline{S})\subseteq \overline{f(S)}$ for $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$

(Note: $\overline{S}$ denotes the closure of S; $\partial S$ denotes the set of boundary points of S)

This is my working:

Let $y\in f(\overline{S})$

Then $\exists x\in \overline{S}$ such that $f(x)=y$

$\Rightarrow \exists x \in S$ or  $\exists x \in \partial S$ such that $f(x)=y$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \in f(S) $ or $f(x)\in f(\partial S)$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \in f(S) \cup f(\partial S)$

$\Rightarrow y\in f(S) \cup \partial f(S) $

$\Rightarrow y\in \overline{f(S)}$

However, I wonder is $f(\partial S)=\partial f(S)$ ?? (If yes, how to prove?)

Is there any other alternative proof for this question?

Comment: The simplest proof is probably by observing that $f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(S)}\right)$ is closed and contains $S$. Hence it contains $\bar{S}$. Then $f\left(\bar{S}\right) \subset f\left(f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(S)}\right)\right) \subset \overline{f(S)}$. That $x\in \partial S \Rightarrow f(x) \in \partial f(S)$ is not true. It can only be asserted that $f(x)\in \overline{f(S)}$. And no, your conjecture is false in general. For example, put $f(x) = x^2$, $S = [-2,0]\cup [1,2]$.

Comment: What does $x\in\bar S$ mean? It means that, if $U$ is any open set containing $x,$ then $U\cap S$ is nonempty. Yes, that is equivalent to the more complicated statement, $x\in S\text{ or }x\in\partial S.$ ***Hint:*** Simple is better than complicated. Usually.

Comment: One thing you should question about your proof: where do you use continuity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $clf(S)$ is closed. Thus, $f^{-1}(clf(S))$ is also closed, and it includes $S$, as $f(S)\subseteq clf(S)$.

Then, it also includes the closure of $S$. Thus, $cl(S)\subseteq f^{-1}(clf(S))$, i.e. $f(clS)\subseteq clf(S)$

Comment: May I know how does $S\subseteq f^{-1}(clf(S))$ imply $clS\subseteq f^{-1}(clf(S))$ ??

I thought $S\subseteq cl(S)$?

Comment: By the definition, if a closed set $U$ includes $S$, it also includes its closure $clS$. Because, $clS=\bigcap_{U\supseteq S, U\text{ closed }} U$

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about this. I will just follow my nose.

Suppose $y\in f(\bar S)$; I want to show that $y\in\overline{f(S)}.$

Let $U$ be any open set containing $y$; I have to show that $U\cap f(S)\ne\emptyset.$

Since $y\in f(\bar S),$ there is a point $x\in\bar S$ such that $f(x)=y.$

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set containing $x.$

Since $x\in\bar S,$ $\ f^{-1}(U)\cap S\ne\emptyset.$

Choose a point $z\in f^{-1}(U)\cap S.$

Then $f(z)\in U$ and $f(z)\in f(S),$

so $U\cap f(S)\ne\emptyset.$ **Q.E.D.**